# How to mock streams in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, node.js-stream

I'm attempting to unit test one of my node-js modules which deals heavily in streams. I'm trying to mock a stream (that I will write to), as within my module I have ".on('data/end)" listeners that I would like to trigger. Essentially I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var mockedStream = new require('stream').readable();

mockedStream.on('data', function withData('data') {
  console.dir(data);
});

mockedStream.on('end', function() { 
  console.dir('goodbye');
});

mockedStream.push('hello world');
mockedStream.close();
```

This executes, but the 'on' event never gets fired after I do the push (and .close() is invalid).

All the guidance I can find on streams uses the 'fs' or 'net' library as a basis for creating a new stream (https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), or they mock it out with sinon but the mocking gets very lengthy very quicky.

Is there a nice way to provide a dummy stream like this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using Push, I should have been using ".emit(<event>, <data>);"

My mock code now works and looks like:

```
var mockedStream = new require('stream').Readable();
mockedStream._read = function(size) { /* do nothing */ };

myModule.functionIWantToTest(mockedStream); // has .on() listeners in it

mockedStream.emit('data', 'Hello data!');
mockedStream.emit('end');
```

Comment: Correction: `new require('stream').Readable()` (note capital R)

Comment: require isn't a constructor, this will work w/o the new keyword

Comment: @Spets require isn't the constructor here though, `Readable` is

Answer (score 47):

There's a simpler way: **`stream.PassThrough`**

I've just found Node's very easy to miss `stream.PassThrough` class, which I believe is what you're looking for.

From [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streampassthrough):

> The stream.PassThrough class is a trivial implementation of a Transform stream that simply passes the input bytes across to the output. **Its purpose is primarily for examples and testing**...

The code from the question, modified:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
const mockedStream = new PassThrough(); // <----

mockedStream.on('data', (d) => {
    console.dir(d);
});

mockedStream.on('end', function() {
    console.dir('goodbye');
});

mockedStream.emit('data', 'hello world');
mockedStream.end();   //   <-- end. not close.
mockedStream.destroy();
```

`mockedStream.push()` works too but as a `Buffer` so you'll might want to do: `console.dir(d.toString());`

Comment: This worked perfectly. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

The accept answer is only partially correct.  If all you need is events to fire, using `.emit('data', datum)` is okay, but if you need to pipe this mock stream anywhere else it won't work.

Mocking a Readable stream is surprisingly easy, requiring only the Readable lib.

```
  let eventCount = 0;
  const mockEventStream = new Readable({
    objectMode: true,
    read: function (size) {
      if (eventCount < 10) {
        eventCount = eventCount + 1;
        return this.push({message: `event${eventCount}`})
      } else {
        return this.push(null);
      }
    }
  });
```

Now you can pipe this stream wherever and 'data' and 'end' will fire.

Another example from the node docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_an_example_counting_stream

Answer (score 7):

Building on @flacnut 's answer, I did this (in NodeJS 12+) using `Readable.from()` to construct a stream preloaded with data (a list of filenames):

```
    const mockStream = require('stream').Readable.from([
       'file1.txt',
       'file2.txt',
       'file3.txt',
    ])
```

In my case, I wanted to mock the stream of filenames returned by fast-glob.stream:

```
    const glob = require('fast-glob')
    // inject the mock stream into glob module
    glob.stream = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockStream)
```

In the function being tested:

```
  const stream = glob.stream(globFilespec)
  for await (const filename of stream) {
    // filename = file1.txt, then file2.txt, then file3.txt
  }
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation which uses `jest.fn()` where the goal is to validate what has been written to the stream created by `fs.createWriteStream()`.  The nice thing about `jest.fn()` is that although the calls to `fs.createWriteStream()` and `stream.write()` are inline in this test function, these functions don't need to be called directly by the test.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const mockStream = {}
    
    test('mock fs.createWriteStream with mock implementation', async () => {
      const createMockWriteStream = (filename, args) => {
        return mockStream;
      }

      mockStream3.write = jest.fn();
      fs.createWriteStream = jest.fn(createMockWriteStream);
  
      const stream = fs.createWriteStream('foo.csv', {'flags': 'a'});
      await stream.write('foobar');
      expect(fs.createWriteStream).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo.csv', {'flags': 'a'});
      expect(mockStream.write).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foobar');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set result as Buffer:

```
const str = '{ "fileName": "file.pdf" }';
const buf = new Buffer(str.length);

for (let i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
  buf[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
}


let eventCount = 0;
const mockedStream = new Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read: function () {
    if (eventCount < 1) {
      eventCount = eventCount + 1;
      return this.push(buf);
    } else {
      return this.push(null);
    }
  }
});
```