# Callback spy does not getting called on stream end

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, tdd, sinon

I can't get my head around why this is not working. I have a module which sends a HTTP POST request containing some payload using the native nodejs http module. I am stubbing the request method with sinon and pass the PassThrough stream for the request and response streams.

**DummyModule.js**

```
const http = require('http');

module.exports = {

    getStuff: function(arg1, arg2, cb) {

        let request = http.request({}, function(response) {

            let data = '';

            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                data += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {
                // spy should be called here
                cb(null, "success");
            });

        });


        request.on('error', function(err) {
            cb(err);
        });

        // payload
        request.write(JSON.stringify({some: "data"}));
        request.end();
    }

};
```

**test_get_stuff.js**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const http = require('http');
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

describe('DummyModule', function() {

    let someModule,
        stub;

    beforeEach(function() {
        someModule = require('./DummyModule');
    });

    describe('success', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            stub = sinon.stub(http, 'request');

        });

        afterEach(function() {
            http.request.restore()
        });

        it('should return success as string', function() {
            let request = new PassThrough(),
                response = new PassThrough(),
                callback = sinon.spy();

            response.write('success');
            response.end();


            stub.callsArgWith(1, response).returns(request);

            someModule.getStuff('arg1', 'arg2', callback);

            sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, null, 'success');
        });
    });
});
```

The spy does not get called and the test fails with  `AssertError: expected spy to be called with arguments`. So the `response.on('end', ...)` does not get called and therefore the test failure. Does the end event on the response stream needs to be triggered somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now. First, the events need to be emitted using the emit [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154121/174326).
Second, the events need to be emitted right after the someModule.getStuff(...) method call:

```
...
someModule.getStuff('arg1', 'arg2', callback);

response.emit('data', 'success');
response.emit('end');

sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, null, 'success');
...
```